# Is there a way to direct Oozie to kill all jobs?

Tags: oozie

I have tried

```
oozie job -oozie http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:11000/oozie -config ./job.properties -kill *
```

...to no effect. I have done a few Google searches and checked Oozie's documentation, and there does not appear to be a command for this.

Would any one know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Note that the oldest two answers appear outdated.

Answer (score 10):

It seems that the recent versions of oozie (tested on 4.2) have made this a lot easier.

Here is a oneliner that I now use to kill all jobs that I created.

```
oozie jobs -oozie  http://myserver:11000/oozie -kill -filter user=dennis -jobtype bundle & oozie jobs -oozie  http://myserver:11000/oozie -kill -filter user=dennis -jobtype coordinator & oozie jobs -oozie  http://myserver:11000/oozie -kill -filter user=dennis
```

First it kills all bundles, then it kills all coordinators and finally all workflows. Note that I set a filter to my own username, as it appears to be mandatory to have a filter set.

---

Update:
As mentioned in the comments by @Nutle:

> Worth noting that (on 4.3 and win7 x64) the suggested command returned
>   a syntax error, solved by enclosing the filter terms in quotes, i.e.
>   `oozie jobs <...> -kill -filter "user=dennis"`

Comment: Nice to have: a way to only kill jobs that are not killed yet (not same as running), to reduce the amount of text dumped on the screen.

Comment: Worth noting that (on 4.3 and win7 x64) the suggested command returned a syntax error, solved by enclosing the filter terms in quotes, i.e. ``oozie jobs <...> -kill -filter "user=dennis"``

Comment: Really nice ! Thanks @DennisJaheruddin

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no such command.

Try a shell script  that [lists](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Checking_the_Status_of_multiple_Workflow_Jobs) the jobs (sadly, workflow jobs, coordinators and bundles should be listed separately), then `grep`s the captions and fancy formatting out, `cut`s the job id and [kills](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Killing_a_Workflow_Coordinator_or_Bundle_Job) them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use below type of code in python . It lists all running coordinator jobs in oozie and then kill them iteratively. You can modify if you want any another statuses as well for killing jobs . Define your oozieURL parameter (like http://localhost:11000/oozie)

```
import os , commands 

def killAllRunningJobs(oozieURL):
    runningJobs = commands.getoutput("oozie jobs -oozie " + oozieURL + " -jobtype coordinator | grep -i RUNNING |  awk -F \" \" '{print $1} " )
    print "Current Running Co-ordinator Jobs : " + runningJobs
    for jobs in runningJobs:
        os.system("oozie job -oozie " + oozieURL + " -kill " + jobs)
```

Answer (score 0):

oozie jobs -oozie oozieURL -filter STATUS=RUNNING -kill

Comment: shall we add an explanation for the answer so anyone can grab it easily and it would be nice.